# OneSignal mutable-content iOS 10

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, ios10, onesignal

I'm new on StackOverflow but I have this problem that I implemented everything to handle the new iOS 10 rich notifications but my push notifications service (OneSignal) doesn't let me configure the payload when sending a push notification. It just let me add custom parameters at the same level that aps, but I need to add the 'mutable-content: 1' inside the aps. Does anyone know how to do it?

Thank you!

Comment: To improve the response you get from your questions, consider doing such things as posting a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [syntax highlighting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work), making your question clear in the title ,[adding necessary tags](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)... and [heading on over to the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OneSignal just released a `mutable_content` option today. Set it to `true` in your payload to the OneSignal [create notification](http://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/notifications-create-notification) REST API POST call.

```
"mutable_content": true
```